# Promise resolving undefined, but data is still POSTED

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, electron

I am trying to post data to my local sqlite database. The data appears in my database table after POST, but the `Promise.resolve()` returns as `undefined`, which in turn doesn't give the result back to client. Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I got.

```
module.exports.addAccount = function (data) {

const db_conn = new sqlite3.Database( path.join(__dirname, "../user_database.sql") )

return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

   db_conn.serialize( function () {
     // insert row
     db_conn.run("INSERT INTO some_table (username) VALUES (?);", [data.username], function (err,rows) {

            if (!err) {
                console.log(rows) // always returns undefined

                resolve([rows, this.lastID])
            } else {
                reject(err)
            }

         })
     })
    db_conn.close()
  })

}
```

Then:

```
app.post("/add-row", function (req, res) {
user_info.addAccount(req.body).then( function(response) {
    
    res.json({
        rows: response[0], // this is undefined
        row_id: response[1] // this is not
    })
}).catch(function () {

})
})
```

Comment: What do you expect the promise to resolve to? The value you inserted? But that you already know, since you provided those values... The only thing you need to know is whether it was successful or not.

Comment: @trincot -- So, do you think that I can run another `db.run` inside the current one to get the row that was just inserted? Because it's still would be on the same connection.

Comment: Why would you want to? You just used INSERT with a value you *know*. So why would you need to get that information *again*?

Comment: @trincot I want to get it from the database. There is something that I need from the database that I don't _know_.

Comment: I don't understand that. I don't see that in your code. Please be concrete in your question. What is there in the database that you don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem:

```
db_conn.run("INSERT INTO some_table (username) VALUES (?);", ['string'], function (err) {
  if (!err) {
    db_conn.get("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE rowid=?", [this.lastID], function(err, rows) {
      db_conn.close()
      resolve([rows])
    })
  } else {
    reject(err)
  }
})
```

I am assuming `rowid` but maybe your table has another primary key. I would also recommend to adopt `async/await` rather than Promise to wait your query to finish before closing the connection.

Comment: Yes! I did this about an hour ago and it worked, only, I closed my connection in `Promise.finally()`. --> [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).